# CSS não carrega na versão mobile ao instalar certificado SSL grátis

Tags: css, htaccess, mobile, ssl

Instalei um certificado SSL https://zerossl.com/ em um site. O certificado está funcionando normal. O problema é que na versão mobile do site o CSS não é carregado, por outro lado, na versão desktop o CSS é carregado normalmente. Desconfio que o problema seja no htaccess. Segue o código do .htaccess que estou usando para redirecionar para HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Usei esse mesmo htaccess em outro site que também instalei o mesmo certificado, e o CSS carregou certinho em ambos os dispositivos. Gostaria de saber se alguém passou por algo parecido e pode me ajudar na resolução desse problema.

Comment: Pode mandar o link do site em questão?

Comment: Olá Vinícius, obrigado pela atenção. Segue o link: https://www.camarapicui.pb.gov.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o caminho absoluto dos arquivos .css, .js.

E por isso, o navegador acusa que tem conteúdo misturado http com https

Use caminhos relativos.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/mdl/material.min.css">
<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/style.css?style=2.9" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/shadowbox-master/source/shadowbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick-1.5.9/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick-1.5.9/slick/slick-theme.css">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, deu certo!. Eu estava utilizando uma urlbase para o site. Usando a sua sugestão deu certo!